# Deep Reinforcement Learning (A3C) for Pong diverging (Tensorflow)

Tags: asynchronous, tensorflow, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I'm trying to implement my own version of the **Asynchronous Advantage Actor-Critic** method, but it fails to learn the Pong game. My code was mostly inspired by [Arthur Juliani's](https://medium.com/emergent-future/simple-reinforcement-learning-with-tensorflow-part-8-asynchronous-actor-critic-agents-a3c-c88f72a5e9f2) and OpenAI Gym's A3C versions. The method works well for a simple Doom environment (the one used in Arthur Juliani's code), but when I try the Pong game, the method diverges to a policy where it always executes the same action (always move down, or always move up, or always executes the no-op action). My code is located in my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/MatheusMRFM/A3C-LSTM-with-Tensorflow).

I have already adapted my network to resemble the architecture used by OpenAI Gym's A3C version, which is:

- 4 convolutional layers with the same specs, those being: 32 filters, 3x3 kernels, 2x2 strides, with padding (padding='same'). The output of the last convolutional layer is then flattened and fed to a LSTM layer with an output of size 256. The initial states C and H of the LSTM layer are given as an input. The output of the LSTM layer is then separated into two streams: a fully connected layer with an output size equals to the number of actions (policy) and another fully connected layer with only one output (value function) (more details in Network.py of my code);
- The loss function used is just as is informed in the original A3C paper. Basically, the policy loss is the *log_softmax* of the linear policy times the advantage function. The value loss is the square of the difference between the value function and the discounted rewards. The total loss accounts for the value loss, policy loss, and the entropy. The gradients are clipped to 40 (more details in Network.py of my code);
- There is only one global network and several worker networks (one network for each worker). Only the global network is updated. This update is done with respect to the local gradients of each worker network. Therefore, each worker simulate the environment for BATCH_SIZE iterations, saving the state, value function, chosen action, reward received, and the LSTM state. After BATCH_SIZE (I used BATCH_SIZE = 20) iterations, each worker pass those data into the network, calculate the discounted rewards, the advantage function, the total loss, and the local gradients. It then updates the global network with those gradients. Finally, the worker's local network is synchronized with the global network (local_net = global_net). All workers does that asynchronously (for more details in this step, check the *work* and *train* methods of the Worker class inside the Worker.py);
- The LSTM states C and H are reset between episodes. It is also important to note that the current states C and H are kept locally by each worker;
- To apply the gradients to the global network, I used the Adamoptimizer with learning rate = 1e-4.

I have already tried different configurations for the network (by trying several different convolutional layers configurations, including different activation functions), other optimizers (**RMSPropOptimizer** and **AdadeltaOptimizer**) with different parameters configurations, and different values to BATCH_SIZE. But it almost ends up diverging to a policy where it always executes only one action. I mean always because there are certain configurations where the agent maintains a policy similar to a random policy for several episodes, with no apparent improvements (I waited until 62k episodes before giving up in those cases).

Therefore, I would like to know if anyone have obtained success in training an agent in the Pong game using the A3C with a LSTM layer. If so, what are the parameters used? Any help would be appreciated!

**[EDIT]** As I said in the comments, I managed to partially solve the problem by feeding the correct LSTM state before calculating the gradients (instead of feeding an initialized LSTM state). This made the method learn reasonably well for the PongDeterministic environment. But the problem persists when I try the Breakout-v0: the agent reaches a mean score of 40 in about 65k episodes, but it seems to stop learning after this (it maintained this score for some time). I have checked the OpenAI starter agent several times and I can't find any significant differences between mine implementation with their's. Any help would be extremely appreciated!

Comment: I have to say Juliani's code is not easy to follow. For learning RL, I'm reading https://github.com/yukezhu/tensorflow-reinforce. It's neat, though didn't solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! I will definitely take a look at this implementation. But I might have discovered my mistake (and, as what it seems, Juliani's mistake as well): when updating the global network by using a batch, I use an initialized LSTM state. The correct is to, when feeding the network with a batch, input the LSTM state that occurred at the first instance of the batch, just as is done in OpenAI's A3C implementation. I'm still running some tests to see if it really solved my problem, but until now, it learns to play PongDeterministic in about 1500 global episodes.